# How do I test that an offset has been committed or not to Kafka

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka, akka-stream

I have an Akka Stream Kafka source that is reading from a Kafka topic.

I have a simple task that is allowing disabling commit of the message offset. The commit is usually done calling commitScaladsl.

My problem is I don't know how to test if the offset has been committed or not.

We usually use EmbeddedKafka for testing, but I haven't figured out a way of asking for the last committed offset.

This is an example of the test I have written:

```
  "KafkaSource" should {
    "consume from a kafka topic and pass the message " in {
      val commitToKafka = true
      val key = "key".getBytes
      val message = "message".getBytes

      withRunningKafka {

        val source = getKafkaSource(commitToKafka)
        val (_, sub) = source
          .toMat(TestSink.probe[CommittableMessage[Array[Byte], Array[Byte], ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset]])(Keep.both)
          .run()

        val messageOpt = publishAndRequestRetry(topic, key, message, sub, retries)
        messageOpt should not be empty
        messageOpt.get.value shouldBe message
      }
    }
```

Now I want to add a check for the offset being committed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it using a ConsumerInterceptor, defined as:

```
class Interceptor extends ConsumerInterceptor[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] {
  override def onConsume(records: ConsumerRecords[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]): ConsumerRecords[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = records

  override def onCommit(offsets: java.util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata]): Unit = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    OffsetRecorder.add(offsets.asScala)
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {}

  override def configure(configs: java.util.Map[String, _]): Unit = OffsetRecorder.clear

}
```

onCommit is called when the commit is done, in this case I just record it. I use configure method to have empty records at the start of each test.

Then, when creating the consumer settings for the source, I add the interceptor as a property:

```
  ConsumerSettings(system, new ByteArrayDeserializer, new ByteArrayDeserializer)
    .withBootstrapServers(s"localhost:${kafkaPort}")
    .withGroupId("group-id")
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, "package.of.my.test.Interceptor")
```

Answer (score 1):

Kafka stores the offsets by the TopicName and PartitionID. So you can use `.committed()` or `.position` method to check the last committed offset or current position of Kafka consumer.

[committed()](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#committed-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-) : Get the last committed offset for the given partition (whether the commit happened by this process or another).

[position()](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#position-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-) : Get the offset of the next record that will be fetched (if a record with that offset exists).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I guess those are methods of Consumer, but I'm not using directly that class. I'm using an Akka Kafka Source, and I don't find a way to use those methods from there. I added an example of another test I did to the question that can clarify what I'm doing (but I'm open to change what is necessary). Please be patient, as I'm a complete newbie with Akka Streams and with Kafka.

Comment: Are you using : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html?

Comment: Yes, the source is created this way:  Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, subscriptions) . But can I access to the consumer later? I haven't found the methods you posted about.